# Most optimal approach to import static website from another repo into wwwroot for ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, static-files, wwwroot

I am creating a self hosted web application with ASP.NET Core 3.1.

A front-end code for this app is built separately in a different repository and is built into a single assets folder.

A backend is and ASP.NET Core project that should have front-end part of the app in its web root folder as per current design.

I would like to have an efficient way of pulling the latest built assets into wwwroot. What would be the best option here?

I tried to package the front-end assets into a nuget package, but the only way to automatically bring in the static assets (not dlls for bin) into the project via nuget is by using a hacky .targets files technique which I didn’t quite got to work as I need.

Any other suggestions on how this challenge could be tackled are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not combine both projects as part of a deployment pipeline?

Comment: @poke local debugging of the back-end APIs will be more complex without the latest version of front-end code available at hand. One could argue that these two need separate testing approaches and thus having back-end tested via real client interface is redundant, I would still want to BE devs to use the client app for the end-2-end testing.